# Social Follow buttons not always rendering - or being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I just added three follow buttons to my blog (Twitter, Google+ & Linkedin). The problem I'm experiencing a.t.m. is that the buttons are not always showing. Only if the page load takes a bit the buttons will display; on pages that load very fast - nothing will be shown. Or almost nothing.

The site is built on wordpress. The java for the follow buttons is loaded in an external file at the end of the page.

By refreshing the page it almost always works, and sometimes also on a first page load. But not very often.

The site can be viewed [here](http://www.webqi.be/leesgedrag-bezoekers-website/).

Note: Total cache is currently active; but the problem existed before total cache was installed. So the problem doesn't seem to reside there.

I've been googling for 2 hours now, but I don't seem to find a solution.

I've tried loading the script in different locations to see if that had an effect. But no.

Is there a way to somehow forceload these buttons before the page load ends?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console when they don't load?

Comment: Hi Tyler, no - no errors seem to pop up. It seems to me that the loading of the buttons falls out of the loop for some reason. That way they only load when they have the time to do so. If the page or post loads too fast - they won't be displayed.